# How to correctly set compatibility_level 110 (2012) for full compatibility?

Tags: sql-server

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2019 installed. One of the DBs is set to compatibility_level 110 (2012).

When I execute the query "SELECT TRIM(' FOO ')" the query runs without error.
But the TRIM function was introduced only in Microsoft SQL Server 2017. How can I make Microsoft SQL Server 2019 behave the same as Microsoft SQL Server 2012 with the specified compatibility_level 110 (2012)?

Thank you all for your reply.

Comment: The purpose of the compatibility flags is to allow older code to continue to work on a newer server. It's *not* the purpose to disallow newer code from also running (in fact, this allows progressive enhancement until the older compatibility mode is no longer required) If you need something that behaves exactly like 2012 in all respects, you need 2012.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent a particular user, or on a particular database, from executing the TRIM function?